# How can I name my txt file with a preferred filename in C Programming?

Tags: c, file, fopen

Good day, I am a freshman. I'm currently studying C Programming. I have all these data and I am to print them to a txt file but the file must be named as *Trip-dd-mm-yyy.txt*

I have the following variables for the dd-mm-yyyy:

```
int month;
int day;
int year;
```

Let's say the input of the user is `month = 12;` `day = 01;` and `year = 2000;` I'm planning to create one whole string for the filename but using `strcat()` combining three (3) strings.

```
FILE * pSource;
char filename[6] = "Trip-";
char fExtension[5] = ".txt";
char dateTrip[11] = "dd-mm-yyyy";

strcat(filename, dateTrip);      //and then just use strcat to combine all of them
strcat(filename, fExtension);

pSource = fopen(filename, "wt");  //and then use filename for fopen()
  .
  .    //then proceed to printing data in the txt file
  .
```

Is this a good approach? If it is, my problem is how do you convert int to char? or include them in a string?

If this is a bad approach, what is a good alternative? Thank you so much.

Comment: The string `"Trip-"` is six characters (including null-.terminator). An array of six character will fit that string, but you can't append to it. Each text you append you do to `filename` will write out of bounds of that array.

Comment: Read about [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Your question could be operating system specific. Read also [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and about [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: As for a way to solve your formatting problem, have you thought of e.g. `snprintf`? As in `snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "Trip-%02d-%02d-%04d.txt", month, day, year)`

Comment: Lesson of the day -- *Don't Skimp On Buffer Size* for the final string. You would rather be 10,000 characters too long than 1-character too short.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `snprintf` , with this function you can also take filename as input from user ,but one point is to be careful about not passing boundaries of your array.

look

```
    FILE* pSource;
    char filename[100];//make sufficient space for your file name
    int month=2;
    int day=4;
    int year=2001;
    int len=snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "Trip-%02d-%02d-%4d.txt", month, day, year);
    if (len < 0 || (unsigned)len >= sizeof filename)
    {
        printf("error in filename");
          return 0;
    }

    pSource = fopen(filename, "wt");
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for suggestion ,I edited my post.

Comment: Also check the return value of snprintf, very likely you want to detect if snprintf did cut of the string because it got to long

Comment: @Rudi thank for suggestion , am doing it right?or shall I check return of `snprinf` in another way?

Comment: I would add a return inside the error handling, since at this point it is known that the string is not complete (and I prefer programs to bail with errors in such situations instead of continue with wrong values).

Comment: As a side note, you can also  let the compiler calculate the buffer size by giving it a template string `char filename[sizeof("Trip-dd-mm-yyyy.txt")]`; But this works here only since here the string has a fixed length (I don't care of any year 10000 problems arising). It is a different thing if the requirement change to include a file path.

Comment: thank you for this! If I were to scan this file, how can I retrieve it the month, day, and year??

Comment: @Lemsic feel free ,no need for thanks ,but if this answer was helpful accept the answer.

Comment: @Lemsic also note in code above I'm not writing anything in file ,filename wont be written in file(unless you are writing them in your own code)